# iOS - trying to understand multitasking, is it restricted to push notifications?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, multitasking

If I have an app running, and I go to my home screen and do other things.  My app is still running.. right?  I know it's able to get push notifications and things like that.  But is it able to run any operations in the background.  For example, if I have my app running in the background is it able to detect an incoming phone call, or detect some other internal events?

Comment: Your app is running in the background and may operate only if the device gives you the opportunity to do so. Sometimes the device might not let you do things in the background if a lot of resources are being used for other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The various background processing modes available to an iOS application are described in the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

If you want to detect an incoming phone call to your app (a VoIP app) then you can use the VoIP background mode.  If you want to detect an incoming mobile phone call then you cannot do this in the background.